# Put a stack-allocated function return value into a unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I came across this problem whilst working within Qt, but the types do not matter; it is the general form of the C++ language that I am confused about.

I want to have a

`std::unique_ptr<QSqlDatabase> database;`

There is a function with this signature

`QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()`

I tried to do something like

`database.reset(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase());`

Of course this failed to compile, because `database` expects a `QSqlDatabase *` and the method call returns a simple `QSqlDatabase`. What do I do if I want to put the return value of `addDatabase()` into a `unique_ptr`? I am stuck because in no place am I using the heap.

Comment: What's wrong in `auto database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase();`? What do you need the pointer for?

Comment: If you're not dynamically allocating the object, why do you think you need a `unique_ptr` to manage it?

Comment: I guess this is a design problem and not a language one.

Comment: You don't want (or need) a unique_ptr in this situation. It is doing the memory management internally for you so that you don't have to even worry about it. It is returning an object so assign it to an object.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could do `database.reset(new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()))`, assuming the presence of a viable copy- or move-constructor on `QSqlDatabase`. But as others have said you likely don't actually need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Loki is probably right, but here's the answer to your question.

```
database.reset(new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()));
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<QSqlDatabase> database(new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase());
```

Either of these copies the result into a heap-allocated QSqlDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that:

```
int work()
{
     QSqlDatabase DB  = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase();


} // DB goes out of scope here and is destroyed automatically.
```